# Fastlane deliver: promote for review

Tags: ios, store, fastlane

I’m using the amazing fastlane toolset to build and upload my iOS app to Apple Store Connect.

I wasn’t able to understand how to promote for review an app already existing in Apple Store Connect.

Which statement should I add to my Fastfile or Deliverfile ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `submit_for_review: true` in the fastfile:

```
deliver(
  submit_for_review: true,
  ...
)
```

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/#use-in-a-fastfile

To select a previously uploaded build and submit it for review run from command line:

```
fastlane deliver submit_build --build_number 830
```

Comment: How could I select by your snippet the IPA version that I'd like to submit for review ? My IPA is already uploaded to Apple Store Connect.

Comment: What about TestFlight external beta build? How I can submit it to beta review with Fastlane?

Comment: Make use of `distribute_external` documented here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/